# Can you use std::string in a 3rd party dll?

Tags: c++, dll

I've been searching for answers for my problem but it seems most people are interested passing std::string across .dll boundaries. But I am more interested in using a std::string in a class that is in a .dll that I am creating.

I am releasing my .dll (emailing) to a group of people on forum I am apart of, so my question is can you use std::string in a .dll without having limitations like compiler needing to be the same, version, CRT needing to be the same, etc.

Can you give me examples on what is not safe and what IS safe?

Example: Would this be safe for the "downloader" to use SetSender function?

Mail.h

```
class _declspec(dllexport) Mail {

    struct ENVELOPE {
        std::wstring SenderEmail; //Should the type be LPWSTR or can it safely be std::wstring
        LPWSTR SenderName;

    }Envelope;

public:
    int SetSender(LPWSTR SenderEmail);
    Mail();
    ~Mail();

};
```

Mail.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Mail.h"

int CoffeeBeans::Mail::SetSender(LPWSTR Email) {
 //Pass LPWSTR instead of std::wstring across .dll boundary

    if (Email == nullptr || lstrcmp(Email, L"") == 0) {
        throw L"Email was either nullptr or empty.";
    }

    this->Envelope.SenderEmail = SenderEmail;
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: I'd say the C string would certainly be safe. So why not pass a read-only C-string?

Comment: I have used a .dll in the past which crashed my program when I used a function which took a std::string (mysqlc++ library), I had to recompile the dll to get it working.

Comment: @PaulStelian Thanks but yes you are very correct, I have been getting in a bad habit of passing wchar* instead of const wchar *.

Comment: Others have addressed your actual question, but I just wanted to mention that, as far as I know,  `throw` is not safe for the same reasons. It _is_ safe to throw within your DLL, as long as you catch within your DLL. When the compilers are different, and you can't safely pass std::string _accross_the_DLL_boundary_ (in either direction), you also can't safely pass exceptions across the boundary.

Comment: @GavinLock Interesting, I didn't know this, too bad because I prefer using throws over returns for errors. Thank you, it prevented a future headache!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a pointer to the string buffer like `LPWSTR`, or `wchar_t*`, etc will always be safe as long as your dll code is not invoking an unspecified behavior (memory is allocated correctly, pointer is initialized, you are not passing pointer to the local buffer, etc). Using an `std::string` will be safe **only** as long, as your dll and a host are using the same CRT version. If versions differ, your strings could cause an Access Violations on any execution stage (usually it happens on the string destruction). You may insure CRT matching by distributing your dll sources or by compiling different dll versions for all existing CRTs (Oracle, for example, does this for their `OCCI` library). This approach of course would not work if a client is not using C++.

Comment: This is exactly what I experienced today with a 3rd party DLL. But is there any MS documentation about this problem?

Comment: @Trantor I have not seen any documentation of such sort.